# error TS2769: No overload matches this call... while upgrading elasticsearch

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch

I am trying to use firestore and elasticsearch. With the help of elasticstore. Elasticstore is dated but was working great in the past and now when i try to update all the dependencies, like updating ts and @elastic/elasticsearch 8.6.1 from 16.7.1, I am running into some errors I can't figure out. This being:

error TS2769: No overload matches this call.

which refers to:

```
  ping = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.esClient.ping((err, result) => {
        if (err) return reject(err)
        else return resolve(result)
      })
    })
  }
```

the line in question here is:

this.esClient.ping((err, result) => {

Please advise on how this should be re written.

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like an attempt to turn the callback based API to promise based but  I think  `@elastic/elasticsearch` already has that out of the box

Comment: I've traced back to see if the correct @elastic/elasticseach is being required and somehow while checking i've missed these on terminal:   at SniffingTransport.request (node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/Transport.js:479:27)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async Client.PingApi [as ping] (node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/api/api/ping.js:37:12)

Comment: "aprokryfos" im loading the correct @elastic/elasticstore, any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: If indeed the callback version of ping is gone then you can try `ping = () => this.esClient.ping()`

Comment: thank you for the response "apokryfos". essentially what i did -and that is checked off of the checklist of how to get elasticsearch to work with version 8..6. If you had any suggestions to a current issue::  {"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] is not supported","status":406}

Comment: From what I gather from the internet that may be due to your @elastic/elasticsearch version not matching your elasticsearch server version e.g. if you're using 8.6 your server needs to be of that version as well. Personally I don't understand that error because I've always used `application/vnd.elasticsearch+json` as a content type for `_bulk` requests ever since elasticsearch 6.8

Comment: thanks "apokryfos" yeah can't even find the elasticsearch version on firestore, currently. I am trying to avoid an elasticsearch subscription on firebase and instead creating an elasticsearch server with node and hosting the cluster on firebase myself. Not sure if this is even possible.. Elasticstore made this possible back in the day..  but the steering of subsciption based services is dominating. Or i don't even know what I am talking about but writing this out here helps me frame the problem. so thanks again. Hope all is well with you :)

Comment: {
  "name" : "3tyb5MT",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "Go0Aau6PRzC2XbWN3ssnJA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.8.23",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "4f67856",
    "build_date" : "2022-01-06T21:30:50.087716Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.7.3",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: there is also a prob with my system version which is 6.8.23. Should I upgrade this to 8.6?\

Comment: I think upgrading 8.6 is a good idea because 6.8 is EOL but be aware that 8.6 is not fully backwards compatible with 6.8 so for now I would try using `"@elastic/elasticsearch": "^6.8"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251518/discussion-between-teoman-kirac-and-apokryfos).